# How to append and remove different appended div´s using jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have built a `form` where you can add a person by clicking a button. Now, I want to add a new button to delete the latest added person. My current code only deletes one person, and after that, I can't add another person again. Do someone know what's wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button1").click(function(){
    $(".flex-container-name-adult").append($(".test1").html());
  });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button3").click(function(){
    $(".test1").remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="flex-container-name-adult">

  <button id="button1">Add person</button>
  <button id="button3">Delete person</button>

  <div class="test1">
    <div class="flex-wrapper-name-adult">
   <span class="adult">Person</span><br>
      <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
      <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Nachname" name="nachname" required>
      <input type="date" class="input" placeholder="Geburtsdatum" name="geburtstag" required onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='Geburtsdatum')">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the `add person` button you are appending the **html** of `test1` to the element with class `flex-container-name-adult`. That **html** don't include the `div` with `test1` class itself. Now, when you click the `delete person` button you are deleting all the elements with the class `test1`. So, after that action, there will be no more elements with class `test1` on the document that you can later use on the `add person` button.

I suggest to use [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) for what you want to do, and to always delete the last added person. Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#button1").click(function()
    {
        // Clone the first ".test1" element and append it to the wrapper.

        $(".flex-container-name-adult").append($(".test1").first().clone());
    });

    $("#button3").click(function()
    {
        // Delete last ".test1" element, if exists more than one.

        let tests = $(".test1");

        if (tests.length > 1)
           tests.last().remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="flex-container-name-adult">

  <button id="button1">Add person</button>
  <button id="button3">Delete person</button>
  
  <div class="test1">
    <div class="flex-wrapper-name-adult">
     <span class="adult">Person</span><br>
      <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Name" name="name" required>
      <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Nachname" name="nachname" required>
      <input type="date" class="input" placeholder="Geburtsdatum" name="geburtstag" required onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='Geburtsdatum')">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```